# BigQuery - Integer showing as date time stamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to insert a row with stream buffer with python code. One of the column is defined as a integer in the table and inserting a long value when I query the table some of the rows showing as date instead of integer.

When I change the column to String it is showing properly. Please let me know why I am seeing this kind of behavior.

Table Definition:
[image: Table Definition]

DATA:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Inserting Data:

{'last_update_time': '2017-09-06 11:46:20', 'loaddate': '2017-09-06', 'download': 0, 'description': 'Impression_Device_xKPIs', 'report_run_id': 703057116554547L}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have Streak BigQuery Chrome Extension installed on your Chrome and it has this "bug"
Just disable it!!

Update:
I just double checked and confirming - it is because of that extension!!